# Koenker & Machado (1999) goodness-of-fit criterion (R1)

Tags: goodness-of-fit, r-squared, quantile-regression

Has anyone come across a journal paper or a book providing a rule of thumb regarding what R1 is appropriate in research that focuses on the impact of macroeconomic or bank-specific variables on bank risk?

Comment: I added the $R^2$ tag because of similarity/analogy to R1.